# Ubuntu 14.04 on vmware player - menu options not visible

Tags: vmware

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on VMware Player 6.
The login screen displays the top pane (such as calendar, time, logout options etc.)
However, after logging in, there is no menu option, either on the top pane, nor on the left side pane. The graphics is a bit distorted on those locations and on hovering, some gradient can be seen.
Also, logout screen has the same issue.
On opening terminal, there is some inverted text displayed on the top and left side of the screen.
Ubuntu 14.04 installed on VMWare Player 6.
Base OS is Windows Vista.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps solved this problem for me:

1. Shut down the guest machine.
2. Right click on VM, and select `Settings`.
3. In `Virtual Machine Settings` window select `Display`, and uncheck the
       `Accelerate 3D graphics` option on the right pane.

Answer (score 0):

Press ALT+CTRL+F1 to login via command line and run following commands.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

`sudo apt-get install unity`

`sudo shutdown -r now`